# INNER JOIN com dois campos da mesma tabela

Tags: mysql, sql

Estou tendo um problema que até o momento não encontrei solução.
Tenho 3 tabelas no MySQL:

- Unidades:contendo informações de "lojas".
- Pedidos: contem as informações do pedido feito pela loja01 para a loja02, ambas cadastradas na tabela unidades.
- Usuários: e por último usuários com informação de quem fez o pedido.

<kbd>[image: modelo de dados]</kbd>

O problema está quando eu tento recuperar as informações de origem e destino que estão ambas na tabela unidades.

```
SELECT
ped.cod_pedido,
ped.origem,
ped.destino,
ped.obs,
ped.usuario,
und.nome_unidade
FROM pedidos as ped
INNER JOIN usuarios as usr ON (ped.usuario = usr.cod_user)
INNER JOIN unidades as und ON (ped.origem = und.cod_unidades)
```

Mas fazendo deste modo não consigo recuperar as informações que necessito só retorna estes resultados:

<kbd>[image: imagem do resultado]</kbd>

Gostaria de fazer com que apareça os nomes das unidades em vez de seu código.

Alguém poderia me ajudar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você precisa fazer 2 joins, um para origem e outro para destino.

```
SELECT
    un_src.nome_unidade as origem,
    un_dst.nome_unidade as destino,
FROM
    pedidos
INNER JOIN unidades as un_src ON un_src.cod_unidade = pedidos.origem
INNER JOIN unidades as un_dst ON un_dst.cod_unidade = pedidos.destino
```

Answer (score 3):

Creio que você pode fazer algo do tipo, mas não tenho como testar aqui:

```
SELECT
ped.cod_pedido,
und_origem.nome as Origem
und_destino.nome as Destino
ped.obs,
ped.usuario,
FROM pedidos as ped
INNER JOIN usuarios as usr ON (ped.usuario = usr.cod_user)
INNER JOIN unidades as und_origem ON (ped.origem = und.cod_unidades)
INNER JOIN unidades as und_destino ON (ped.destino = und.cod_unidades)
```